# Notepad++ remove all menus

Tags: notepad++, window

I know that I can open notepad in full window by pressing F11.

Is there any way to remove ALL menus like "full window mode" but with minimized window?

Example of notepad without menus:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to press F11/F12, np++ will change their view mode. To delete buttonst from toolbar use Customize toolbar addon.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution with [WallOfBytes’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1186299/358766).

First, go to preferences and hide toolbars and don't see status bar,
as shown below:

[image: Preferences settings]

Next press <kbd>F12</kbd> in a minimized window, and the result is:

[image: Result]